# What's the minimum Raspberry Pi that can display the output from the Raspberry Pi camera at 30fps in real time?

Tags: camera, raspicam, real-time

Setup:

- A Raspberry Pi of some kind (TBD depending on answers to this question)
- A Raspberry Pi camera of some kind (TBD depending on answers to this question)
- A 1080p television, that will be connection to the Raspberry Pi over HDMI

Requirements:
Displaying the output of the Raspberry Pi camera on the television

- at 30fps
- in real time (not sure exactly what I would count as real time, but at most a very small number of frames delay, preferably ~1)
- minimum 720p, preferably 1080p

Questions:

- What's the minimum Raspberry Pi version that can achieve this?
- What's the minimum Raspberry Pi camera version that can achieve this?

Comment: Good luck trying to find a TV with a delay of ~1 frame. OLED screens may get you a single-digit number, but on a typical LCD the picture only comes after 10+ frames.

Comment: Pretty sure my first pi (model 1B) and first camera (r1.0?) would do HD at 20-30 fps... I mostly used the camera at a lower res though (for network bandwidth) so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My response which is qualified below would be Raspberry PI Zero (W if you want WIFI) V1.3 and a Raspberry PI Camera V2.1 via CSI-2.

I recommend MotionEyeOS if you want an quick/easy method of getting streaming working.I'm comfortable compiling up motion with mal_ driver support but I recognise thats not everybody's cup of tea.

https://raspberry-valley.azurewebsites.net/MotionEye-OS/

IMHO this represents the most cost effective hardware and a decent quality camera.

I have three headless Raspberry PI Zero (1.3) with CSI connected Raspberry PI Cameras V2.1.   I use them to stream at 30fps.  They all run the stock 32Bit Raspberry PI OS.

I use motion application on the RPI)'s but have turned off motion detection so its just used for streaming.  This is because there is no way a RPI0 can do motion detection at 30fps however it can stream as long as your network bandwidth is up to the task.

I have configured the RPI0 as Ethernet USB-Gadgets which means they are powered and use the networking over a single Micro-USB cable to a single hub which also acts as a router and homebridge server which means I can access the cameras from any Apple device.  iPhone, iPad, Apple TV etc.

The hub also runs motion and it does the motion detection on the 3 cameras and is setup to do movement alerts via homebridge.